# Unwanted symbol to string conversion of hash key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing, rspec, rspec2

When I assign in my controller

```
@my_hash = { :my_key => :my_value }
```

and test that controller by doing

```
get 'index'
assigns(:my_hash).should == { :my_key => :my_value }
```

then I get the following error message:

```
expected: {:my_key=>:my_value},
got: {"my_key"=>:my_value} (using ==)
```

Why does this automatic symbol to string conversion happen? Why does it affect the key of the hash?

Comment: You really should set your Gravatar because of your awesome username.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It may end up as a `HashWithIndifferentAccess` if Rails somehow gets ahold of it, and that uses string keys internally. You might want to verify the class is the same:

```
assert_equal Hash, assigns(:my_hash).class
```

Parameters are always processed as the indifferent access kind of hash so you can retrieve using either string or symbol. If you're assigning this to your params hash on the `get` or `post` call, or you might be getting converted.

Another thing you can do is freeze it and see if anyone attempts to modify it because that should throw an exception:

```
@my_hash = { :my_key => :my_value }.freeze
```

Comment: It's indeed a HashWithIndifferentAccess. I wonder a bit why Rails does convert my standard hash into that one. I am not assigning it to anything else than mentioned above (and especially not to params). Do you maybe also know why Rails does that conversion between the controller and the view (as mentioned no params are used in the above example).

Comment: Yes, this seems a bit silly why it is being converted to a `HashWithIndifferentAccess`

Comment: Rails automatically converts incoming parameters to the indifferent access hash so that you don't need to concern yourself with strings or symbols when referencing it. `params[:foo]` and `params['foo']` end up being equivalent. This is probably, in part, to help PHP, Perl and Python developers that aren't used to symbol keys, and avoid having to remember what the keys are stored as.

Comment: I don't think it's Rails, but Rspec that's actually causing the issue.  I'm having the same problem.  I'll try to post an answer below, since this question came up when I searched for my problem, even though it's 5 years old! ;) This article explains more: http://ryanoglesby08.github.io/blog/2012/12/26/rails-controller-specs-dont-always-play-nice-with-hashie/

Answer (score 10):

You might try calling "stringify_keys":

```
assigns(:my_hash).should == { :my_key => :my_value }.stringify_keys
```

Comment: Solved my problem.. do you know any method working with nested hashes?

Answer (score 1):

AHA! This is happening not because of Rails, per se, but because of Rspec.

I had the same problem testing the value of a `Hashie::Mash` in a controller spec (but it applies to anything that quacks like a `Hash`)

Specifically, in a controller spec, when you call `assigns` to access the instance variables set in the controller action, it's not returning exactly the instance variable you set, but rather, a copy of the variable that Rspec stores as a member of a `HashWithIndifferentAccess` (containing all the assigned instance variables).  Unfortunately, when you stick a `Hash` (or anything that inherits from `Hash`) into a `HashWithIndifferentAccess`, it is automatically converted to an instance of that same, oh-so-convenient but not-quite-accurate class :)

The easiest work-around is to avoid the conversion by accessing the variable directly, before it's converted "for your convenience", using: `controller.view_assigns['variable_name']` (note: the key here must be a string, not a symbol)

So the test in the original post should pass if it were changed to:

```
get 'index'
controller.view_assigns['my_hash'].should == { :my_key => :my_value }
```

(of course, `.should` is no longer supported in new versions of RSpec, but just for comparison  I kept it the same)

See this article for further explanation:
http://ryanogles.by/rails/hashie/rspec/testing/2012/12/26/rails-controller-specs-dont-always-play-nice-with-hashie.html

Comment: The link 404s now. :(

Comment: If someone else is still looking for the link posted in the answer, http://ryanogles.by/rails/hashie/rspec/testing/2012/12/26/rails-controller-specs-dont-always-play-nice-with-hashie.html

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but if you are upgrading from Rails-3 to 4, your controller tests may still have places where `Hash` with symbol keys was used but compared with the stringified version, just to prevent the wrong expectation.

Rails-4 has fixed this issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/5082 .
I suggest updating your tests to have expectations against the actual keys.

In Rails-3 the `assigns` method converts your `@my_hash` to  `HashWithIndifferentAccess` that stringifies all the keys -

```
def assigns(key = nil)
  assigns = @controller.view_assigns.with_indifferent_access
  key.nil? ? assigns : assigns[key]
end
```

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/testing/test_process.rb#L7-L10

Rails-4 updated it to return the original keys -

```
def assigns(key = nil)
  assigns = {}.with_indifferent_access
  @controller.view_assigns.each { |k, v| assigns.regular_writer(k, v) }
  key.nil? ? assigns : assigns[key]
end
```

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/testing/test_process.rb#L7-L11

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass your `Hash` object to the initializer of `HashWithIndifferentAccess`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HashWithIndifferentAccess.new` as Hash init:

```
Thor::CoreExt::HashWithIndifferentAccess.new( to: 'mail@somehost.com', from: 'from@host.com')
```